# Accessing system modules from vs code python interactive window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using the VS code interactive window and using some python packages that make use of other programs. In the interactive window I am e.g. getting error messages like:

```
OSError: No command "mcflirt" found on host login2.nan.kcl.ac.uk. Please check that the corresponding package is installed.
```

If I was just running this from the command line I would simply ensure that I loaded the package which contains 'mcflirt' into the shell before starting the python interpreter and the interpreter would then be able to find it. Is anyone aware of how to tell the interactive window to load the package (e.g. loading the mcflirt containing package by `module load fsl`)before starting the python interpreter?

Comment: What code did you run in "Interactive" or did it display this message after performing any operation? Could you please provide us with an example that can minimize the recurrence of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One way to access system modules is to use the python 'init' file e.g.:

```
sys.path.insert(0,'/software/system/modules/4.5.1/init')
import python as mod
mod.module('unload', 'fsl')
mod.module('load', 'fsl/6.0.4')
mod.module('load', 'ants/2.3.5')
```